# How to mock NGXS select in child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngxs

I am trying to unit test a component that has a child component that I need to mock? Or provide real components not so bed idea like all talk? Problem in `childCopm.user$`, it throw error what:

```
TypeError: SelectFactory.store.select is not a function
        at createSelectObservable (node_modules/@ngxs/store/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ngxs-store.js:3835:1)
        at ChildApiComponent.get [as user$] (node_modules/@ngxs/store/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/ngxs-store.js:3904:1)
        at ChildApiComponent.ngOnInit (src/app/pages/... path to OnInit method)
```

I have child select:

```
@Select(UserState.getUser) user$: Observable<IUserInfoResponse>;
```

parents unit test looks like:

```
describe('AddAccountComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let apiComponent: AddAccountApiComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddAccountComponent>;
  let apiComp: ComponentFixture<AddAccountApiComponent>;
 ... services
  let store: Store;
  

  const mockDialogRef = {
    close: jasmine.createSpy('close'),
  };

  @Component({ selector: 'app-add-account-api', template: '' })
  class StubChildApiComponent{
    user$ = of(mockUserResponce);
  }

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      const storeSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Store', ['dispatch']);
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        imports: [
          FormsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          AddAccountModule,
          NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
          NgxMaskModule.forRoot(options),
          NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
          RouterTestingModule,
          MatDialogModule,
        ],
        declarations: [
          ParentComponent,
          ...
          StubChildApiComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
          {
            provide: Store,
            useValue: { storeSpy },
          },
         ...
        
        ],
      }).compileComponents();
      store = TestBed.inject(Store);
    
    }),
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    apiComp = TestBed.createComponent(StubChildApiComponent);
    apiComponent = apiComp.componentInstance;
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    Object.defineProperty(component, 'user$', { writable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(component, 'addAccountStep$', { writable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(component, 'isMobile$', { writable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(component, 'apiComp', { writable: true });
    component.isMobile$ = of(null);
    component.user$ = of(mockUserResponce);
    component.apiComp = apiComponent;
    component.apiComp.user$ = of(mockUserResponce);
   
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });
});
```

I tried to redefined select, and for parent its work well, and for child well too in childs unit test, but not from here. When I trying to provide `StubChildApiComponent` I got error, but when I want to do `component.apiComp.user$ = of(mockUserResponce);` seen another error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property user$ of [object Object] which has only a getter
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/pages/add-account/add-account.component.spec.ts:132:28)
```